# WCF: Using a 64Bit DLL with 32bit app

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, dll

I am using VS '15 and a solution with two projects.  The first project is a GUI app that uses 32 bit DLLs.  These DLLs are not offered in 64 bit.  I also need to reference a few 64 bit DLLs that arent offered in 32 bit.  This is why i made the second project in the solution a WCF project.

I have used the built in WCF testing interface to make sure simple things like strings and numbers can be passed back and forth to the WCF host.  But when i pass a byte[] that gets passed to a 64bit DLL file, it breaks at the first reference to the DLL.  Am i missing something?

I am compiling the solution with "AnyCPU" selected.  I feel like i might be overlooking something simple because my understanding is WCF should take care of this.

My question is this, am i shooting myself in the foot by using the same solution for each project?

Comment: Honestly, we are not magicians.  How in the world could we answer this question?  You have given us *so little* information...can you ask a specific question?

Comment: so i guess my question is, is it possible to reference a 64Bit DLL in my WCF project (which is in the same solution as my 32Bit windows form application)?  Do i need to have two seperate solutions? If its not possible, is there another way to take use a 64 bit DLL function in a 32 Bit app? @roryap

Comment: A solution is just for keeping different projects together in the editor. Having different solutions doesn't change anything for the compiled application. Each project is standalone, it doesn't matter wether they're in a solution or not.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that your app will only work on 64-bit machines, as 32-bit machines cannot run 64-bit applications nor 64-bit DLLs.

Comment: You should enable tracing on your WCF service to determine why it is failing: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023(v=vs.110).aspx